# Highcharts boxplot custom labels for maximum quartiles median and minimum?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, boxplot

I want to change the tooltip labels of the maximum, upper quartile, median, lower quartile and minimum for the highcharts boxplot. I would assume that this is possible but can't find a solution. Here is a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daxton/7ta0m5s9/13/) of the basic boxplot I have now.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'boxplot',
    inverted: true,
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
        lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
    }
},
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
            enabled: false,
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Observations',
    data: [
    [760, 801, 848, 895, 965]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tooltip and read the `point` values as is shown in this example:

Example:

```
// Set the tooltip:     
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        //// Use this for hover the cursor over the graph and view the 
        //// F12 developer tools - console - for get the results you need:
        // console.log(this); 
        // read values as :
        // this.y (it's the maximun value) = 965
        // this.point.low (it's the minimun value) = 760
        // this.point.median (it's the median value) = 848
        return 'The maximun value is <b>' + this.y +
            '</b> and the minimun value is <b>' + this.point.low + '</b>';
    }
},
```

Here's the [modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/psn0cyr6/).